# Recommendations for a pannable-zoomable view of a single large image?

Tags: android

I want to display a large-ish image, around 800 x 800 pixels. I'd like to be able to pan it in all four directions by dragging with a finger. I'd also like to be able to zoom in and out. I need to be able to know the pan values and zoom values, because I have to draw small text strings at certain locations over the image.

For example, if the pan is 100 pixels to the right, I need to know that so I can add that offset to all my elements.

Wondering what a good way to do this is. Should I implement it myself in the paint method within a View I implement? Is there some other standard method of doing it? It's essentially like a google maps view, only one large tile, but I have to draw my pins on top of it with pan and zoom,

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to start off with a ScrollView so that you have native dragging. It might have cropping so that it only shows a fixed area of your image at a time too.

Comment: I am looking to do similar.  I found this https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/custom-scrollable-image-view no luck yet grasping how to utilize, but maybe you can make some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i tried some months ago with no success, at last i just load the images inside a webview enabling the zoom controls and i was able to do the panning of my image...

```
public class PhotoZoom extends Activity  {

    private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.BOTTOM);

    private WebView PhotoZoom;
    private long lastTouchTime = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_zoom);                  

        PhotoZoom = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.PhotoZoom);        
        PhotoZoom.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String Photoname = bundle.getString("URLPhoto");        
        PhotoZoom.loadUrl("content://com.jorgesys.pan/sdcard/myimages/" +fotoname);  

        WebSettings webSettings = PhotoZoom.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);       

        FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View zoom = PhotoZoom.getZoomControls();

        mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
        zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```